# Ionic 3 / Cordova Admob Rewarded Video Ads

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, ionic3

Tried to make the Admob Rewarded videos work in Ionic 3 but couldn't make it happen! the ad doesn't trigger, have searched around stack and ionic forum but couldn't find a healing answer, I'm using **Admob-free plugin**

Here's what I have so far:

```
async showRewardedAds() {
    try {
      const rewardedConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        id: "ID goes here...",
        isTesting: false
      }
      this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.config(rewardedConfig);
      const result = await this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.prepare();
      await this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.show();
      console.log(result)
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

Whether I'm emulating it on Android or browser, nothing seems to work!
Could anyone have some ideas or encountered this before?

- Android platform version: android@6.4.0
- Ionic v3

Comment: have you checked by putting isTesting = true? check whether you are getting the test Ads. Production Ads will come only after some time and it depends on the availability. Reward video will not come in browser. you can check in emulators and real devices.

Comment: yeah checked but no luck

Comment: Do USB debugging and check the console for logs, check in catch block

Comment: the result is literally `OK`

Comment: Did you manage it to work?

Comment: did you try in the config autoShow: true? and also please try to create a release build (e.g. ionic cordova build android --prod --release) and see, because you used isTesting: false.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this plugin, but reading the docs ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/ )
I think you should try something like this, handling the catch and the success of the promise

```
showRewardedAds() {
      const rewardedConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        id: "ID goes here...",
        isTesting: false
      }
      this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.config(rewardedConfig);
      this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.prepare().then((data:any)=>{
        // HERE YOU WILL NEED TO MAKE THE SAME THING
        // catching the Error or the Success of the Promise
        this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.show()
      })
      .catch((e:Error)=>{
         console.log("Error ",e);
      });
  }
```